# Virtual attributes and inheritance super with Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, virtual-attribute

I'm taking a ruby fundamentals counse in pluralsight but some of the code from the instructor isn't working. Could someone please explain what's missing & why whatever is missing is needed? Thank you so much

```
class Probe
  def deploy(deploy_time, return_time)
    puts "Deploying"
  end
end

class MineralProbe < Probe
  def deploy(deploy_time)
    puts "Preparing sample chamber"
    super(deploy_time, Time.now + 2 * 60)
  end
end

Mineralprobe.new.deploy(Time.now)
```

The error I'm getting is this:
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Users/-/RubymineProjects/test1/probe.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
C:/Users/-/RubymineProjects/test1/probe.rb:14:in `': uninitialized constant Mineralprobe (NameError)
Did you mean?  MineralProbe

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I think the message, `uninitialized constant Mineralprobe (NameError) Did you mean? MineralProbe` is very clear and quite helpful already. What part of that error message are you having trouble with?

Comment: `Mineralprobe.new.deploy(Time.now)` should be `MineralProbe.new.deploy(Time.now)`  

watch out the case since Ruby is case-sensitive

Comment: ohhhh wow I'm dump ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple type the class is called

```
class MineralProbe < Probe
             ^
```

but you try to initialize an instance of

```
Mineralprobe.new.deploy(Time.now)
       ^
```